# How to get elements with a specific attribute with IHTMLDocument2?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am  using C# (console application) to pull down a DOM from a URL using the `WebClient` class and parsing the HTML with the `IHTMLDocument2` interface.

Currently, I'm able to access all img elements in the DOM using:

```
//string htmlContent is defined somewhere above as stream returned from WebClient response

IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = (IHTMLDocument2)new mshtml.HTMLDocument();

htmlDocument.write(htmlContent);

IHTMLElementCollection myImages = htmlDocument.images;
```

Does anyone know of a way I can use the `IHTMLDocument2` (or other) interface to grab only img elements with a specific class? What about any element with a specific class/attribute?

Comment: You are likely looking for [querySelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if it is available on that/related object.  Side note: It would be much safer to parse HTML with HTMLAgilityPack and you'll find way more samples doing so.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks for the tip. I'll look into querySelector and the HTMLAgilityPack. I'm hoping to do as much of this without bringing in additional libraries, so I'll see what I can accomplish with the former first